# Ruby grouping/sorting by attribute and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have been struggling with this and after some searching, I haven't been able to find anything online. Users choose from several study session dates (their first choice is the one that is the most convenient for them) and I store their choices as Id's that correspond to the chosen dates. The Id's are stored as an array for each user (ex: [1,3,2,4]). Each study session has a capacity, so what I need to do is sort it by their first choice but if their first choice is over the capacity, I need to place them into their second choice. So far, I have the grouping by first choice done but I don't know how to place all users who are over the capacity into their second choice. Here is my code so far:

```
<% @choices.all.group_by { |choice| choice.choice.first}.each do |date, choices| %>
  <%= @options.where(:id => "#{date}").first.date.strftime('%B %d, %Y') %> 
  at 
  <%= @options.where(:id => "#{date}").first.time.strftime('%l:%M %P') %>
  <ul>
  <% choices.each do |sort| %>
    <li><%= sort.name %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would help if you showed the models involved and at least the one method of the controller that's being invoked. I'll say that in general it looks like you'd benefit from pushing more functionality into your models so that your views are simpler. But without seeing more code, I don't think anybody's going to be able to offer much constructive guidance.

Comment: @ToddAgulnick this is a small project that I am building to help out my professor. I am trying to make it the simplest as possible (students don't make an account). I don't have anything in my models or controllers that would help answer this question. Thanks!

Comment: Really? Nothing at all? Your question says you want to make decisions based on capacity, for instance, but your code doesn't show anything about how that's implemented. How do you expect someone who hasn't seen any of the implementation to help you?

Comment: @ToddAgulnick each study session has capacities set by my professor. My problem is that I need to figure out how to do the sorting based on capacity. I can do this: <% if option.capacity >= choices.count %> but it will just cut off at the limit and not show the rest of the users. That is my problem. I need to figure out what to do when the count is over the capacity.

Comment: Well, based on what you _have_ shown, I'm pretty confident that that is not your only problem. You have a model whose id is a date string, you have models whose names are generic and thus devoid of meaning (options, choice), you have models with attributes that are the same as the model name (choice.choice), and you say that you're storing an array of id's, which, assuming you're using ActiveRecord is just not the way things are done. I think you're trying to reach for an algorithm here, but without more context, I certainly can't help. Maybe others can. Good luck!